# returning a POST response without providing an location URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a sign up and sign in route in my API project. The sign up route should return the created user, the sign in route should return the json web token.

I'm wondering what to return as a response when I don't want to provide a location URI. `Created` expects a location URI

```
return Created("what to pass in here", user);
```

same for the `CreatedAtAction`

```
return CreatedAtAction("what to pass in here", null, user);
```

I also tried to return the result only like so

```
return user;
```

but then the statuscode is 200 and not 201. I tried so simplify my current code

```
[HttpPost("signUp")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> SignUp(UserCredentialsDto userCredentialsDto)
{
    User user = null; // create a new user

    return null; // return a 201 with the user
}

[HttpPost("signIn")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SignIn(UserCredentialsDto userCredentialsDto)
{
    string token = ""; // generate a new token

    return null; // return a 201 with the token
}
```

How can I leave out the location uri for both endpoints or what is the correct ActionResult to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SignUp

   It is totally correct to respond with 201, because you CREATE a new resource which is a `user`. It is one of good api practices to return a route to get a brand new resource. In the example below the response object will include this route to a `Location` header.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("SignUp")]
   public ActionResult<User> SignUp()
   {
       var newUser = new User() { Id = 1 };
       return Created($"/users/{newUser.Id}/test1", newUser);
   }
   ```
2. SignIn

   IMHO it is better to use just `200 OK` because you don't create a new resource when request for a token. What code to return is a separate topic, so I provided a way how you can achieve what you asked below. The idea is just to use `ContentResult` instance and specify the code explicitly:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("SignIn")]
   public ActionResult<string> SignIn()
   {
       return new ContentResult
       {
           Content = "token",
           ContentType = "text/plain",
           StatusCode = 201
       };
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much. For the sign in part it makes sense :) When signing up I don't want to provide a resource link because the users shouldn't be able to access this route (it doesn't even exist). So should I also return a `ContentResult` without the `ContentType` property for this?

Comment: Probably you may use suggestion #2 as well for sign up if the route doesn't exist. In my experience I added a /api/me route, so every user can see someinfo about himself, consider this as an option too